# How can I omit interface by union type recursively in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, typescript2.0

I'd like to omit recursively by type that includes in union types,
and remove some union types

Here's the example.

Normal and Admin must be union types

```
interface Admin {
    admin: never;
}

interface Normal {
    normal: never;
}


interface A {
    a: number;
    b: Admin | number;
    c: Normal | string;
    d?: number | string | null;
    e: {
        f: Admin | string;
        g: number;
    };
    h: {
        i: {
            j: Admin | number;
            k: string;
        };
    };
    l: Normal | boolean;
}


type OmitNormal = OmitRecursiveByType<A, Admin>;
```

And I want the result like this.

```
{
    a: number;
    c: string;
    d?: number | string | null;
    e: {
        g: number;
    };
    h: {
        i: {
            k: string;
        };
    };
    l: boolean;
}
```

In this case, key that has Admin union type is removed.
However key that has Normal isn't removed.

Here is another example

```
interface A {
    a: number;
    b: Admin | number;
    c: Normal | string;
    d: null|number
}

type OmitAll = OmitRecursiveByType<A, Admin|Normal>;
```

result

```
{
   a: number;
   d: number|null;
}
```

Here's the other example

```
interface A {
    a: number;
    b: string;
    c: number|string;
    d: number|null;
    e: {
       f: string;
       g: number|null;
    }
}
type NotStringA = OmitRecursiveByType<A, string>
```

result

```
{
    a: number;
    d: number|null;
    e: {
       g: number|null;
    }
}
```

How can I make OmitRecursiveByType<T, P>?

Comment: In your rssult `Normal` is also omitted, but it is not passed to `OmitRecursiveByType`. Is it a typo?

Comment: And `Normal` is being redefined?  Please [edit] so this is a [mre] without any unrelated issues.

Comment: aaand `Admin | string` is equivalent to `string`, so you can't really  "exclude" it in a consistent way

Comment: You haven't addressed @wonderflame's comment (how do you know to omit `Normal`?), and you've still got typos.  Please test it out in an IDE or something so we don't have to fix typos for you, if you don't mind.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wgaa1m) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Please note how @wonderflame wrote `OmitRecursiveByType<A, Admin | Normal>` in their suggested answer, but you wrote `OmitRecursiveByType<A, Admin>;` in yours.  If you mean `Admin | Normal`, please [edit] to show that.  Otherwise, how would anyone know to omit `Normal` when you don't mention it?  This is the third time the question has been asked so I'm sorry if it's repetitive, but you haven't addressed it yet.

Comment: I'm hopelessly confused now (more so after the edits) so I think I need to disengage.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your help. I add extra eaxmples, fix typo.

Comment: @saroro does my approach work?

Comment: @wonderflame   Oh I checked, but it doesn't work. I used first example. const c : OmitNormal = {} as OmitNormal; c.b = 1 // it doesn't occur error

Comment: Please, include the whole use case. there is no `b` in the `c` in the example you've added. and what you are passing to omit?

Comment: @wonderflame [Here is the example](https://tsplay.dev/Wz774w)

Comment: your original code snippet removes only `Admin` in the union, not the whole property. Please make sure that you don't make confusions

Comment: Oh I make you confuse, If I use OmitRecursiveByType<A, string>, all keys that have string type must be removed. After remove key type, I would also like to exclude Normal, Admin types whether I pass Admin generic or not, such as number|Admin to number.

Comment: and how I should figure out if the passed type should remove the whole property or not?

Comment: After remove key that has type, Admin and Normal type must be excluded. [Here is another example](https://tsplay.dev/mxJJbw) (Add BType). I apologize that I give you insufficient information

Comment: I visually can see the difference between Admin and string. But what if `Admin = string`. How should I determine?

Comment: That could not be possible. Admin and Normal type is not duplicated with primitive type. I make this type because of sql selection statement.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description and examples it sounds like you need the following:

- If the value type of a property overlaps with `P`, the property is removed.
- If the value of a property is an object, the step above is applied recursively.
- At the end, all occurences of `Admin` and `Normal` are removed.

If this sums up your problem, it should be solved by the following type:

```
type OmitRecursiveByType<T extends Object, P> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object
    ? OmitRecursiveByType<T[K], P> 
    : Extract<T[K], P> extends never
      ? Exclude<T[K], Admin | Normal>
      : never
}
```